# Может ли частица ведь относиться к деепричастному обороту?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

Подобный пример разбирался на форуме: **Ведь не будучи финансово и территориально привязанным к одному месту.**..

Деепричастные обороты любят обособлять с двух сторон, так как по Розенталю "деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой".

**Но это союзы, а частицы входят в состав оборота:** Понять это произведение можно, **только учитывая** условия его создания; Выучить иностранный язык можно, **лишь постоянно** занимаясь им.

Сюда же можно отнести и частицу ***ВЕДЬ.***

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

Из другого источника:

3. В состав деепричастного оборота могут входить частицы **ЛИШЬ, ТОЛЬКО**, которые не отделяются от деепричастного оборота запятой, например: Она сидела молча, **только слегка улыбаясь.**

Точно так же не отделяются запятой и сравнительные союзы КАК БЫ, БУДТО, ТОЧНО, СЛОВНО, СЛОВНО КАК, стоящие в начале деепричастного оборота, например: Александр Владимирович подождал с ответом, точно желая отделить своё слово ото всего, что было сказано (Ф.);

http://doc.knigi-x.ru/22metodichka/370071-2-seriya-sovremenniy-russkiy-yazik-tkachenko-punktuaciya-pravila-uprazhneniya-diktanti-chast-p.php

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**1) Союз или частица?**

**ВЕДЬ. I. частица.** Употр. **для усиления** основного содержания всего высказывания (предположения, утверждения, вопроса и т.п.) или выделения, подчёркивания отдельного слова. В. приди я вовремя, этого бы не случилось.  **II. союз. 1.** Присоединяет предложения, содержащие указание **на причину**, обоснование предыдущего высказывания. Полагаемся на тебя, ты в. один знаешь дорогу. Пора домой, в. уже поздно. 2. **Несмотря на то, что; хотя**. В. и сил нет, а работаешь. В. говорил вам, да не послушались.

Еще пример для союза: Да и как они ухитрились, ведь немец-то втрое больше их был

Итак, слово ***ведь*** может быть **присоединительным** союзом, при этом оно находится **во второй части предложения** (если только нет явной парцелляции).

Союз этот имеет дополнительное значение **причины, уступки, условия**, можно заменить союзами ТАК КАК, ХОТЯ, ЕСЛИ.

**2) Оборот  *ведь не будучи***

**Ведь не будучи** финансово и территориально привязанным к одному месту..

Синонимичная конструкция: **Ведь если** ты финансово и территориально не привязан к одному месту...

Частица относится к условному союзу и всему придаточному предложению.

ВЫВОД: **Скорее всего, это именно частица и обособлять ее не нужно.**

Answer (score 2):

Может входить,

> (Он сам виноват.) **Ведь** не будучи финансово и территориально привязанным к одному месту,
>   а просто пребывая в состоянии лени, он отказался от этого делового
>   предложения.

а может и не входить:

> (Не надо печалиться.) **Ведь,** не будучи финансово и территориально
>   привязанным к одному месту, можно жить припеваючи.
>
> (= **Ведь** можно жить припеваючи, не будучи финансово и территориально
>   привязанным к одному месту.)

"Входимость" зависит от того, что в высказывании является *аргументом*, на который указывает "ведь": глагольная конструкция (тогда не входит) или связанный с ней деепричастный оборот (входит). В обоих примерах это союз.